# SO and NOT with verbs other than THINK, SUPPOSE, HOPE, etc

Tags: neither-nor, so

I'm aware than we can use **so** after some verbs instead of repeating an object clause, especially in short answers. The verbs we do this with most are: **appear, assume, believe, expect, guess**, etc. A typical sentence of this type would be:

> -Are you having a party tomorrow?
>
> -I guess **so**

My question is as follows: Can we use **so** in a similar way in a combination with other kinds of verbs? For example, with: **plan, consider,** etc?
Like in the following example:

> -Are you having a presentation on Friday?
>
> -I`m planning **so**

OR

> -Are you moving to NY next year?
>
> -I'm considering **so**

Answer (score 1):

[**CONVENTION:** *In my answer when I say **Verb Phrase** or in short **VP**, I mean a verb attached with an auxiliary verb (if any) along with its complements and modifiers.*]

The word - *so* - as used in your question is a **Pro-form**. A pro-form, as you must know, substitutes a string of words or a single word. Not only that it can even substitute a whole clause or a phrase.

Generally in **Verb Phrase** structure the **Pro-form** - *so* - substitutes complements. Various word categories can form a complement. It can be a phrase (a Noun Phrase, an Adjective Phrase, an Adverb Phrase, a Preposition phrase etc), a finite clause or even a non-finite clause.

> We are planning *to visit Goa next month*. [Marked in italics the complement here is a non-finite clause, a *to*-infinitive clause introduced by the subordinator *to*.]
>
> I expect *that everything is going to be alright soon*. [Marked in italics the complement here is a finite clause, introduced by a subordinator *that*.]
>
> I like *him* and she likes *the way I get attention from the crowd*. [Marked in italics the complements here are Noun Phrases.]
>
> Please don't treat *[him] [badly]*. [Marked in italics. Here there are two complements, marked by third brackets. One complement is a Noun Phrase and the other complement is an adverb.]
>
> We remain *hopeful of your success*. [Marked in italics the complement here is an adjective phrase.]

The **Pro-form** - *so* - can substitute complements formed by most of clauses and phrases.

> Were they sad to see you? I think *so*. [*so* here substitutes a finite clause, introduced by the subordinator - *that they were sad to see me*.]
>
> A large percentage of school-age students were overweight, or at the risk of becoming *so*. [*so* here substitutes an Adjective Phrase headed by an adjective - *overweight*.]
>
> The two had become friends, the closest of friends, and remained *so*. [*so* here substitutes a Noun Phrase - *the closest of friends*.]
>
> I can't ride that thing. Oh come on! You can *so*. [Here *so* substitutes a Verb Phrase (VP) - *ride that thing*. Notice that in this VP that *so* substitutes the auxiliary verb is not included. I believe this kind of substitution that *so* offers here is only limited to *Spoken English* or in *Fictions* where real-life speech is imitated. This is very colloquial. You are not going to find any other auxiliary verb to work with *so*, the way *can so* is used.]

It, however, can't substitute complements formed by some clauses or phrases. For example generally it can't substitute a *to*-infinitive complement or a Gerund-Participle clause as complement, or an Adverb Phrase as complement.

> Are you moving to NY next year?
>
> I'm considering so [INCORRECT]

**Verbs whose complements can be substituted by *so* are -**

> Think, Guess, die, Look, Feel, Become etc.

**N.B -** The verb - *like* - is not among the verbs whose complement can be substituted by *so*. Yet you probably can find similar sentences and they are correct -

> Then you add your tomato, *like so*.

*like so* here is a set expression, meaning *in this manner*.

---

All the quoted sentences with *so* in your question are correct, except the one with *consider so*.

Comment: I think you're on the right track; but I think you'll find that in this S-V-so construction *so* only refers to finite complements, not infinitivals, gerundials or participials. In effect, only verbs which take *that* clauses qualify, and not all of those: *confirm, doubt, realise, resent* don't--and neither does *consider* in the sense in which OP uses it. See *CGEL*, Ch.17,§7.7,1534-40.

Comment: @StoneyB Thank you for the reference. Actually I was looking for some sort of reference from the very beginning. I will surely look into it and edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no: with consider and plan you cannot use so as you use it in: I guess so.

Please note: **so here is the same as: I guess I will**.

VERSUS: I'm planning to and I'm considering it.

This list of verbs takes so: appear, assume, believe, expect, guess,think,seem (partial list), look (one meaning of look)

**These are not "action" verbs. They are verbs of expectation or belief**.

Plan and consider are action verbs.

/So/ can stand for the auxiliary in many cases.

Do you think so? I think I do.

Did you or would you think so?- I thought I did or I thought I would

Have you thought so? I thought I have or had

Will you think so tomorrow? I think I will.

I will pass on providing any heavy grammar. That doesn't really help an ELL.

Whoops, I forgot the negative:
I don't think so = I don't think I go.
I didn't think so = I didn't think I did. 
It doesn't seem so =It doesn't seem it did.